# WSO2 - Fails to redirect when the session is timed out

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have created an custom authentication endpoint, like https://www.custom-auth.localpc, which is being redirect to by WSO2 when i try to login which is working.
However, when I submit the loging with a sessionkey which has expired already, WSO2 replies with a 302 that redirects to http://localhost:9443/https://www.custom-auth.localpc?loginStatus=true.

How can I set a new redirect when this time-out happens? Or send back to the custom authentication endpoint, with an error preferably.

Comment: What is the identity server version you are using?

Comment: The version is 5.1

Comment: Can you try with applying security patches for IS 5.1.0 and carbon 4.4.0 mentioned at http://wso2.com/security-patch-releases/?

Comment: If I apply those,  what should be the expected behavior?

Comment: Ideally if you are time out, you are expecting to be redirected to login page, aren't you? Anyway I would suggest you to try this in IS authentication endpoint without customizing, so that we can figure out is this a problem in IS or in your customization.

Comment: Hope you have also configured the <AuthenticationEndpointRetryURL> at repository/conf/identity/application-authentication.xml. At an error WSO2 authentication framework will redirect to the url configured in above location. If you have configured so, seems the issue you are facing has been caused due to a bug identified in WSO2 IS 5.1.0 version tracked with [IDENTITY-4315](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4315).

Comment: @ChamilaWijayarathna Indeed, the issue was fixed with the security patches.
However, WSO2 redirects back to the page without any query paremeters that were sent previously. Is there a way to send them again?